# I am trying to find a specific element in my list and its not functioning right, idk why?

Tags: python

I want print out the position that an element is in, in the list

```
list = [A,B,C,D]
position=list.find("B")
print ("This is at " + position +" of the list")
```

Answer (score 1):

`index` method could be one of the options but it would only give the first occurrence. If there are multiple occurrences, then I would recommend something like this

```py
value_list = ["A","B","C","D","A"]

occurances = [index for index, element in enumerate(value_list) if element == 'A']

#answer - [0,4]
```

Comment: I think @chapter473 gave the right answer but I would like to add that taking a reserved word like "list" as a variable name is a very bad idea.

Comment: aah.. my bad. Updated the answer to reflect the same!